# what is the defference between 'I don't have anything' and 'I have nothing'

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

1. I don't have anything.
2. I have nothing.

What is the differnece between them?
I wanna know the nuance, because to me they just look the same.

Comment: The second is more emphatic.

Comment: Please check your spelling.  You should have a spell checker with your browser. Use it!.  Also don't use "wanna". The correct spelling is "want to", even if you might say "wanna", this is not the correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same. The usual phrasing is "I don't have anything."

You might use "I have nothing" to be more emphatic or to add variation to your writing. You can add adverbs, for example "I have absolutely nothing". You couldn't do this with "I don't have anything."